# Python return csv file for d3.js bar chart

Tags: python, csv, d3.js, flask, jinja2

I need to draw a bar chart where the data is stored in `csv` format generated from Python.
The bar chart source code is:

```
    
    
    
function renderChart() {

var data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select('#csv').text());
var valueLabelWidth = 40; // space reserved for value labels (right)
var barHeight = 20; // height of one bar
var barLabelWidth = 100; // space reserved for bar labels
var barLabelPadding = 5; // padding between bar and bar labels (left)
var gridLabelHeight = 18; // space reserved for gridline labels
var gridChartOffset = 3; // space between start of grid and first bar
var maxBarWidth = 420; // width of the bar with the max value

// accessor functions 
var barLabel = function(d) { return d['month']; };
var barValue = function(d) { return parseFloat(d[' count']); };

// scales
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(0, data.length)).rangeBands([0, data.length * barHeight]);
var y = function(d, i) { return yScale(i); };
var yText = function(d, i) { return y(d, i) + yScale.rangeBand() / 2; };
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data, barValue)]).range([0, maxBarWidth]);
// svg container element
var chart = d3.select('#chart').append("svg")
  .attr('width', maxBarWidth + barLabelWidth + valueLabelWidth)
  .attr('height', gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset + data.length * barHeight);
// grid line labels
var gridContainer = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + barLabelWidth + ',' + gridLabelHeight + ')'); 
gridContainer.selectAll("text").data(x.ticks(10)).enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", x)
  .attr("dy", -3)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(String);
// vertical grid lines
gridContainer.selectAll("line").data(x.ticks(10)).enter().append("line")
  .attr("x1", x)
  .attr("x2", x)
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("y2", yScale.rangeExtent()[1] + gridChartOffset)
  .style("stroke", "#ccc");
// bar labels
var labelsContainer = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (barLabelWidth - barLabelPadding) + ',' + (gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset) + ')'); 
labelsContainer.selectAll('text').data(data).enter().append('text')
  .attr('y', yText)
  .attr('stroke', 'none')
  .attr('fill', 'black')
  .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
  .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
  .text(barLabel);
// bars
var barsContainer = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + barLabelWidth + ',' + (gridLabelHeight + gridChartOffset) + ')'); 
barsContainer.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
  .attr('y', y)
  .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
  .attr('width', function(d) { return x(barValue(d)); })
  .attr('stroke', 'white')
  .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
// bar value labels
barsContainer.selectAll("text").data(data).enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(barValue(d)); })
  .attr("y", yText)
  .attr("dx", 3) // padding-left
  .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
  .attr("text-anchor", "start") // text-align: right
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("stroke", "none")
  .text(function(d) { return d3.round(barValue(d), 2); });
// start line
barsContainer.append("line")
  .attr("y1", -gridChartOffset)
  .attr("y2", yScale.rangeExtent()[1] + gridChartOffset)
  .style("stroke", "#000");

}
    
    month, count
2010-10,6
2010-11,13
2010-12,7
2011-01,10
2011-02,2
2011-03,6
2011-04,8
2011-05,9
2011-06,9
2011-07,1
2011-09,11
2011-10,8
2011-11,7
2011-12,4
2012-03,10
2012-04,7
2012-05,10
2012-06,2
2012-07,10
2012-09,8
2012-10,11
2012-11,13
2012-12,7
2013-01,1
2013-03,11
2013-04,9
2013-05,5
2013-06,3

    renderChart();
```

The question is: how can I return a csv file as a path  or insert something in csv format to `bar.html`(let's named it so) which should be parsed by `jinja` . Hum, in `python` and `flask` environment.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want to load the CSV dynamically from a given URL?

Comment: Yes. The csv data is dymamic.

Comment: So you want [`d3.csv`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Sure. Python got a `csv` module but seems not support dump csv like `json` dumps, as I wanna return something like json dumps object but in `csv` format called by `d3.js`

Comment: Sorry, you lost me there. If you can generate JSON easily, why not use JSON?

Comment: Oh, I should use JSON!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549585/d3-js-json-simple-sample-code